# How to integrate an dynamically generated JSON Object into an other object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I put this JSON Object in the function or object below?

```
// this function generates an JSON Object dynamically       
$(".n_ListTitle").each(function(i, v) {
    var node = $(this);
    var nodeParent = node.parent();
    var nodeText = node.text();
    var nodePrice = node.siblings('.n_ListPrice');

    var prodPrice = $(nodePrice).text();
    var prodId = nodeParent.attr('id').replace('ric', '');
    var prodTitle = nodeText;

    var json = {
        id : prodId,
        price : prodPrice,
        currency : "CHF",
        mame : prodTitle
    };
    return json;
});

TDConf.Config = {
    products : [
        // here should be inserted the JSON Object
        {id: "[product-id1]", price:"[price1]", currency:"[currency1]", name:"[product-name1]"},
        {id: "[product-id2]", price:"[price2]", currency:"[currency2]", name:"[product-name2]"},
        ...

    })],
    containerTagId :"..."
};
```

If it is not understandable please ask :)
Thanks in advance for helping me to figure out!

Comment: Please, explain better the issue. Do you want insert as items as n_listTitle elements in products array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not do what you think it does ( the `return` statement inside `.each` can only break a loop ). Try this:

```
TDConf.Config = {
    products : [],
    // some other stuff
}
$(".n_ListTitle").each(function(i, v) {
    // some other code
    var json = {
        id : prodId,
        price : prodPrice,
        currency : "CHF",
        name : prodTitle
    };
    TDConf.Config.products.push( json );
});
```

You should learn more about JavaScript, scoping and obviously JSON, because you don't seem to understand that what you are dealing with is actualy not JSON, it's a JavaScript object ( slight difference but still a difference ).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
     TDConf.Config = {
        products : []
     };

     $(".n_ListTitle").each(function(i, v) {
        var node = $(this);
        var nodeParent = node.parent();
        var nodeText = node.text();
        var nodePrice = node.siblings('.n_ListPrice');

        var prodPrice = $(nodePrice).text();
        var prodId = nodeParent.attr('id').replace('ric', '');
        var prodTitle = nodeText;

        var json = {
            id : prodId,
            price : prodPrice,
            currency : "CHF",
            name : prodTitle
        };
        TDConf.Config.products.push( json );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add it to `TDConf.Config.products` then you would do:

```
TDConf.Config.products.push(theDynamicJsonObj);
```

If you want to add/overrite the properties of an existing `TDConf.Config.products` element then youd do:

```
TDConf.Config.products[theNumericIndex] = $.extend(TDConf.Config.products[theNumericIndex], theDynamicJsonObj);
```